# No visible @interface for 'NSFileManager' declares the selector 'AESEncryptFile:toFile:usingPassphrase:error:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I want to encrypt an xml file. I am trying to follow this link [strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html)

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] AESEncryptFile:@"/path/to/input file" toFile:@"/path/to/output file" usingPassphrase:@"My secret password" error:&error])
{   
        NSLog(@"Failed to write encrypted file. Error = %@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AESEncryptionErrorDescriptionKey]);
}
```

while typing the code I got this error:

> No visible @interface for 'NSFileManager' declares the selector 'AESEncryptFile:toFile:usingPassphrase:error:'

I have included in header

```
 #include <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
```

how do I overcome this error? did I miss including or declaring something?

Answer (score 0):

NSFileManager doesn't come with that method in the iOS SDK, which is why you're seeing the `No visible @interface for 'NSFileManager' declares the selector 'AESEncryptFile:toFile:usingPassphrase:error:'` compiler issue.

But you may be able to jump over this hurdle by incorporating the code which came from this blog post by Jeff LeMarche:  http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html (look for the zip file link)

Comment: Thank you @Michael will try this link [link] (https://github.com/appwgh/Encryption) . the zip file link when clicked shows a black empty page.

Comment: Ah, I see why it's a blank empty page.  The top of Jeff's post says "Please do not use this code! Instead, check out [Jim Dovey's Common Crypto code from AQToolkit.](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master/CommonCrypto)"

Comment: @1218GG The Dovey code is also way out-of-date. One good current encryption source is [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), it handles all the details that are needed to use encryption securely, it is being currently maintained and is well vetted. If for some reason that does not meet your needs add more information to the question.

Comment: Thank you @Zaph will have a look at the link you have provided. All I want to do is: I have a xml file with some data, I want to encrypt that file and later decrypt it whenever my app needs to read from the file. I am looking for a full proof security kind of stuff, if possible. I am working on a iOS app.